Deciphering terse CNN specifications
I'm reading a paper about three CNNs, described in a terse way that I cannot decipher (usually the case for space-efficient papers). Likely, this is due to my ignorance and I wonder if anyone can apply educated guesses to calculate the number of parameters per layer of these CNNs:

The input to the CNNs are 32x32x3. Bonus points if someone can connect the models to standard architectures. Model 2 is a bit like LeNet but not exactly.

I think it would be useful for others to specify the name of the paper :)

Model 1 and Model 2 are very basic CNNs, I would say LeNet-style but with max pooling (MP) instead of average pooling. Instead, Model 3 resembles a very small VGG net.
Then regarding parameter count, if c means kernel size (assuming also padding=same otherwise MP won't work at some point) then:

Model 1:

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0

 conv2d_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 12)        912

 max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPoolin  (None, 16, 16, 12)        0
 g2D)

 conv2d_13 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 64)        19264

 max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPoolin  (None, 8, 8, 64)          0
 g2D)

 flatten_4 (Flatten)         (None, 4096)              0

 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 10)                40970

=================================================================
Total params: 61146 (238.85 KB)
Trainable params: 61146 (238.85 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________


Model 2:

_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0

 conv2d_14 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 32)        2432

 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPoolin  (None, 16, 16, 32)        0
 g2D)

 conv2d_15 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 64)        51264

 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPoolin  (None, 8, 8, 64)          0
 g2D)

 conv2d_16 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 32)          51232

 max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPoolin  (None, 4, 4, 32)          0
 g2D)

 flatten_5 (Flatten)         (None, 512)               0

 dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 100)               51300

 dense_9 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1010

=================================================================
Total params: 157238 (614.21 KB)
Trainable params: 157238 (614.21 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________


Model 3:

_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0

 conv2d_17 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 32)        896

 conv2d_18 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 32)        9248

 max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPoolin  (None, 10, 10, 32)        0
 g2D)

 conv2d_19 (Conv2D)          (None, 10, 10, 64)        18496

 conv2d_20 (Conv2D)          (None, 10, 10, 32)        18464

 max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooli  (None, 3, 3, 32)          0
 ng2D)

 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 288)               0

 dense_10 (Dense)            (None, 512)               147968

 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 10)                5130

=================================================================
Total params: 200202 (782.04 KB)
Trainable params: 200202 (782.04 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________

I think the architectures should be close enough to what you're showing.

What is the max pooling in the last model doing?

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert In the last model you have MP(p3s2) which I interpret as pool_size=3 (or kernel_size=3) with stride=2: this is usually called overlapping max-pooling because the sliding window is larger than the strides, and so some pixels are considered multiple times when downsampling.
